# Get Index of Control in an Control-Array

Tags: c#, arrays, controls, indexing

I have a TextBox Array

```
private TextBox[,] Fields = new TextBox[9, 9];
```

and all the TextBoxes have got the same TextChanged-Event

```
void Field_Changed( object sender, EventArgs e )
```

Is there a way to get the Index of the sender in the Array (without giving each TextBox it's own EventHandler)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do you really need the index, the sender is a reference to the instance that send the request.
2. If the answer to 1 is yes, you can put the index in the ['Tag'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) property of the textbox and then query that.
3. Alternatively you can search the array for the instance that matches the `sender` argument of the event.

Answer (score 1):

You'll pretty much have to loop through your array and do a reference equality check on each text box.

Either that or assign the index to the tag when you insert the controls to the array.  But this is a micro optimization not really worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving each textbox it's own `Tag` or `Name` on initialization, Then you can cast `sender` to a TextBox and look at either of those properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the objects and find the one whose reference equals the sender:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, Fields[i, j])) 
            Console.WriteLine(i + " " + j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking an eye out the [Array Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array_members.aspx) might help.

The ones you're particularly looking for are the `IndexOf()` methods. There are multiple overloads. Choose the one that best suits your needs.

Comment: Works only with one-dimensional Arrays as far as I can see.